# $\int_C\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = 0$ for $f$ analytic, $f'$ continuous and $C$ closed

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that $\int_C\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = 0$ for $f$ analytic, $f'$ continuous on some set $\Omega$ and $C$ closed and contained in $\Omega$. Moreover, the function satisfies $|f(z) -1 | < 1$ in $\Omega$. Now at this point, I do not know that if $f$ is analytic, I can write in as a power series locally, and hence its derivatives all exist at that point and are analytic themselves.

If I manage to show that $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ is analytic, given $f(z) \neq 0$ in $\Omega$ then the statement holds based on a theorem I already proved. Or is there some other approach to show this?

Thank you for your insight!

Comment: What's an analytic function for you?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Cauchy-Riemann Holds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The fact that $|f(z)-1|<1$ for all $z\in\Omega$ tells you that there is a branch of logarithm in $f(\Omega)$. So the function $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ has an antiderivative there. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on the branch of logarithm point?

Comment: $f(\Omega)$ is a domain in $\mathbb{C}$ which doesn't include the origin and is fully contained in the right half plane. And in the right half plane it is known there is a branch of logarithm. (for example define the logarithm with argument between $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$)

Comment: I can finish from where you left off! Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.